# To show a function is integrable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I came across this question while studying for my exam:
To show the function $f(x) = \frac{(\sin x)^2}{x^2}$ is Lebesgue integrable on [0, $\infty$). I wonder if there is any smarter way of proving it (like, using absolute continuity) without going all the way back to the definition. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A standard way to show that a "complicated" non-negative function is integrable is to find an integrable upper bounding function (for which integrability is simpler to prove).

Since for all $t$, $|\sin t|\leqslant \min\{|t|,1\}$, we get for $x$ positive,
$$0\leqslant \frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}\leqslant \chi_{(0,1]}+\chi_{(1,+\infty)}\frac 1{x^2}.$$

Comment: Thanks Davide. But a function f could be non-Lebesgue integrable and have an upper bounding function that is Lebesgue integrable. For example, take f(x) = |sinx/x|. Then 0< f(x) < (the upper bounding function in your answer). But sinx/x is not Lebesgue integrable on [0, \infty)

Comment: Why it is smaller than the upper bounding function I gave?

Comment: Sorry I meant it is smaller than X_[0, 1] + X_[1, \infty)1/x

Comment: Which is most definitely not integrable. To add a hint to @DavideGiraudo's suggestion, use Dominated Convergence.

Comment: @TedShifrin, I suppose that's because the Riemann integral of X_[1, \infty)1/x is infinity. But by "integrable", I think we allow a class of function whose integration gives infinity. After this class of functions satisfy the limsup-and-liminf definition of Lebesgue integrability trivially. Did I make a misunderstanding of the definition? Thanks

Comment: I think you might be confusing Lebesgue-measurable and integrable.